# Can we ask questions about the anime series for summer 2013 already?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, acceptable-questions

I looked at the [poll](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/602/what-are-good-series-to-ask-about-for-summer-2013) for which upcoming series we could ask questions about.

This left me with a question about Gatchaman Crowds - will it take place in the same universe as the original Gatchaman series? Googling did not answer it, and I think this will not be answerable until the series starts. But by then, it *will* be answerable.

I looked at [this question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331/is-asking-about-upcoming-on-hiatus-manga-anime-off-topic) on meta, but I think the examples there are mostly questions that can only be answered with speculation. The question I have should be answerable with facts, if not now, then by July.

So, would it be OK to post it? Or should I wait until the series starts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes!

It's perfectly fine asking question that you **know that it's likely to have a factual answer in the near future**.

Meaning, asking about something that's going to happen in the future (but in the future *will* have a good answer), is OK.

Go ahead and ask your question, don't be discouraged if you don't get any answers at first (because... you know.. there aren't any).